# How can I prevent this ndash from disappearing at small font sizes?

Tags: css, fonts

I have an `&ndash;` character that becomes invisible when the text is rendered at a smaller font size (the applicable font-size rule is 14px, at which it is invisible; if I zoom in one level in Firefox, it becomes visible.)  I have only seen this behavior on Firefox on Windows.  With Firefox on Linux, I see the character at all sizes.  I believe that what happens is that at smaller sizes, the dash is allowed to render as a line of zero width.  So the question is, how can I remedy this?  Here's what I can think of -

- Try a different dash character and hope for the best
- wrap the dash in a span and force it to be bigger - seems clunky
- maybe my font definition is broken - this is embedded Open Sans

any other approach I'm overlooking?

Comment: is there any span or similar around that character that causes it to be rendered smaller than the surrounding text in the paragraph?

Comment: no; it's just "blah &ndash; blah"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use any of the legacy 90's Microsoft core fonts in Windows (Arial, Verdana, etc). They have very aggressive hints intended to prevent "fat" or "blurry" stems at all costs, that result in some of those stems disappearing at small sizes. Perpetuating the pixelated look Windows users were accustomed to was the only thing Microsoft cared about at the time (there are built-in workarounds in the Microsoft rendering stack to hide the bugs of those fonts, but they don't exist in third-party apps).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different font-family to see if it's showing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of fonts, not browser support. Try to use another font like "Times New Roman" to verify.

In the case of the small icons, the most reliable solution is to use the CSS @font-face rule to ask the browser to download a particular font. Then you'll know for sure that the user has an appropriate font installed. There are even some fonts designed specifically for this use, with extra icons built in: "Font Awesome" is a well-known example.

Please look here for more information: [Does every browser support all unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183061/does-every-browser-support-all-unicode)