# My website cannot display all unicode emoji characters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, emoji

I am using PHP 5.6 and MySQL,I can use and display some unicode characters on my website  like these:
❤ ✓ ☀ ★ ☂ ♞ ☯ ☭ ☢ € ☎ ❄ ♫ 
but when I try to use these unicode emotions:   ,the result is just "????".
I've tried many times to change utf8 to ut8mb4 but it's still the same result.
What's my false here,I can't understand.How can I handle this matter?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15183294/6448640

Comment: The column _and_ the connection need to be `utf8mb4`.  Else, 4-byte UTF-8 characters will turn into question marks.