# What's the benefit of using emojis in CSS?

Tags: html, css, unicode, emoji

I've noticed a trend of using emojis for CSS classnames.

```
.-Vg{color:#ff4040}
.VDe{padding:.75rem 0;font-size:1rem}
```

It makes certain things more difficult. e.g. writing Selenium tests over these pages.

Is there a real benefit to using them?  Security? Filesize? 
Or are developers just doing this for kicks?

**Edit: For the "Close (Opinion Base)" voters.  I genuinely want to know if there's a development reason for doing this.  I'm not looking for people's opinions here.**

Comment: It is a byte saving technique however its such a pain for maintainability later and other devs, **please do not do it**. 
Also I don't think this Q should be closed if only to scream to everyone else about reasons for not doing this.

Comment: To follow up on my comment, if you need to reduce bytes and are serving an ungodly amount of requests to justify this practice, then you probably wont be in SO looking at this question. However a good use case of the *for* argument : https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/05/30/journey-in-native-unicode-emoji/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going to tenatively answer this while trying to not to be too 'Opinion based'

The 'emoji' support is a feature of supporting all Unicode characters, this was to support Chinese charachter support, which makes perfect sense.

As Emojis have been mapped to the Unicode chars, they came out of the wash too.

I have trouble finding legitimate references to bytes saved with emojis in-lieu of another method. So if someone could correct me that would be helpful. 
The closest I found was a gitLab document from 2018 which moreso speaks to the performace improvements they saw implementing the native Unicode emojis.

[GitLab Emoji Unicode](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/05/30/journey-in-native-unicode-emoji/)

Appart from anything else though, I have seen some companies throw them into CSS files to attract some 'UI' enthusiasts while browsing the source of a site, for hiring purposes.

*Opinion Spoiler* - If I saw this in a company content, the last thing I would be doing is applying to work with that.

*Final Note*

This really is not useful in any practical way, if you are working as part of a team, ask them yourself how they would feel about searching through a source base using an emoji/unicode instead of some readable class/reference.

*Reading Material*

[Browser Support SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183061/does-every-browser-support-all-unicode)

[CanIUse Unicode](https://caniuse.com/#search=unicode)

[Unicode Release with Emoji Support](http://blog.unicode.org/2016/06/announcing-unicode-standard-version-90.html)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read from a forum, the reason people use emojis is because it can shave bytes off of files and it is easy to understand.
As far as I know this is not a security thing.

Comment: *it is easy to understand* --> how emoji is easy to understand?

Comment: And also, I'm programming on a physical keyboard, not on a phone's virtual keyboard. That makes it a little harder to input these characters.