# legitimate to put unicode in CSS content?

Tags: html, css

I'm putting my unicode that I use often in a table, into CSS and would like to know if this is legitimate to do so.
e.g.

CSS:

```
.check::before {
  content: "✔";
  color: green;
}

.cross::before {
  content: "✘";
  color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
 <td><span class="check"></td>
 <td><span class="cross"></td>
 <td><span class="check"></td>
```

This gets me a cleaner html coder that is also easier to maintain. I just don't know if this is legitimate or might cause any troubles in some browsers. :)

Thanks

Comment: This Unicode is supported by 98% of browsers ( the 2% is Opera mini with its all versions ), so we can say its supported.

Comment: As long as you ensure that the encoding is right. Many browsers assume that in the absence of any explicit encoding, CSS files will have the same encoding as the parent HTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , this is legitimate to add Unicode characters in css ,just make sure that add below meta tag to support in each browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for sure, nowadays all web browsers are giving support for the Unicode so you can definitely use the Unicode values in the content property of CSS as below:

```
.check::before {
     content: "\2713";
     color: green;
}

.cross::before {
     content: "\2715";
     color: red;
}
```

That is the correct way to use the Unicodes. But if you put the resultant character of Unicode in the content property of CSS it will not be legitimate.

Here is the link for Unicode references:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp

[image: content property support]

It was obviously the depends on the installed fonts on the machine as referenced here: 
[Does every browser support all unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183061/does-every-browser-support-all-unicode)

I hope it will help you.